# Google Maps is not covering the whole screen when clicked on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, background-size

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#button {
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -25px;
margin-left: -75px;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
background-color: #4081FB;
font-size: 18px;
border: solid 1px #4081FB;
}
#button:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
#map {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#button").click(function () {
$("#map").fadeIn("slow");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Open Map" />
<div id="map">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d26496.05743213355!2d151.12773775!3d-33.88946895!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1439976442653" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why the Google Maps iframe is not covering the entire screen when i click on the button. I have set the iframe to background-size: cover; to cover up the whole screen once i have clicked on the button. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height on the #map as well as change the inline css on the iframe.

- Add height/width (100vh,100vw) on `#map`
- Change inline html attributes height/width (100%,100%) on the `<iframe>`

//HTML

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d26496.05743213355!2d151.12773775!3d-33.88946895!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1439976442653" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

//CSS

```
#map {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;

    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Jordan,

You need to allow `#map` to spread across the screen so give it

```
   #map {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%; }
```

And then make the iframe spread across `#map` div so the iframe code will be: `width="100%" height="100%"` replacing `width="600" height="450"`.

Also, at the end you can remove the whitespace outside `#div` you may add a zero-margin to the body.

```
body { margin:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do three things:

1. Specify the `width:100%;`, `height:100%;` and `margin:0px;` for your body.

THEN

2. Specify the `width:100%;` and `height:100%` for your map div.

AND

3. Remove the inline width and height of the iframe and specify the `min-width:100%` and `min-height:100%` for your iframe.

---

Here's a jsfiddle with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/65sf2f66/20/

And here's the codes using SO's snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#button").click(function () {
$("#map").fadeIn("slow");
});
});
```

```css
body  {
    width:100%;
    height:0%;
    margin:0px;
}
#button {
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -25px;
margin-left: -75px;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
background-color: #4081FB;
font-size: 18px;
border: solid 1px #4081FB;
}
#button:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
#map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
#map iframe {min-width:100%;min-height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Open Map" />
<div id="map">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d26496.05743213355!2d151.12773775!3d-33.88946895!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1439976442653" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```